# Deleting a row of supercolumns and immediately replacing it with new data

Tags: cassandra

Say I have a row of super-columns in Cassandra. I delete the entire row (it is now marked with a tombstone). I then immediately (before any compaction / nodetool repair) add different data with the same exact row-key.  My question is, does Cassandra properly handle this and delete the data, or is there a risk of sstables being orphaned that should have been deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all depends on the timestamps.  The later timestamp wins....so if deletes timestamp is before the modification timestampt, modification wins and puts stuff in there.

Dean

PlayOrm for Cassandra Developer